# C#: Different ways to run this code asynchronously?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, multithreading

I have this code

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();

myList.AddRange(new MyClass1().Load());
myList.AddRange(new MyClass2().Load());
myList.AddRange(new MyClass3().Load());

myList.DoSomethingWithValues();
```

What's the best way of running an arbitrary number of Load() methods asynchronously and then ensuring DoSomethingWithValues() runs when all asynchronous threads have completed (of course without incrementing a variable every time a callback happens and waiting for == 3)

Comment: If the subject of asynchronous control flows interests you, consider looking into the CTP for the next version of C# / VB: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/async.aspx -- We would love to get user feedback at the forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/async/threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ani's conceptual solution can be written more concisely:

```
new ILoadable[] { new MyClass1(), new MyClass2(), new MyClass3() }
    .AsParallel().SelectMany(o => o.Load()).ToList()
    .DoSomethingWithValues();
```

That's my preferred solution: declarative (AsParallel) and concise.

Reed's solution, when written in this fashion, looks as follows:

```
new ILoadable[] { new MyClass1(), new MyClass2(), new MyClass3() }
    .Select(o=>Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>o.Load().ToArray())).ToArray()
    .SelectMany(t=>t.Result).ToList()
    .DoSomethingWithValues();
```

Note that *both* `ToArray` calls may be necessary.  The first call is necessary if `o.Load` is lazy (which in general it can be, though YMMV) to ensure evaluation of `o.Load` is completed inside the background task.  The second call is necessary to ensure the list of tasks has been fully constructed before the call to `SelectMany` - if you don't do this, then `SelectMany` will attempt to iterate over its source only as necessary - i.e. it won't iterate to the *second* task before it has to, and that's not until the first task's `Result` has been computed.  Effectively, you're starting tasks but then lazily executing them  one after the other - turning background tasks back into a strictly sequential execution.

Note that the second, less declarative solution has many more pitfalls and requires a much more thorough analysis to be sure it's correct - i.e., this is less maintainable, though still miles better than manual threading.  Incidentally, you may be able to get away with leaving out the calls to `.ToList` - that depends on the details of `DoSomethingWithValues` - for even better performance, whereby your final processing can access the first values as they trickle in without needing to wait for all tasks or parallel enumerables to complete.  And that's even shorter to boot!

Answer (score 8):

My personal favorite would be:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();

var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => new MyClass1().Load() );
var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => new MyClass2().Load() );
var task3 = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => new MyClass3().Load() );

myList.AddRange(task1.Result);
myList.AddRange(task2.Result);
myList.AddRange(task3.Result);

myList.DoSomethingWithValues();
```

Comment: This may not work as expected if `Load` is implemented as lazily evaluated `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 5):

How about [PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx)?

```
var loadables = new ILoadable[] 
                { new MyClass1(), new MyClass2(), new MyClass3() };

var loadResults = loadables.AsParallel()
                           .SelectMany(l => l.Load());

myList.AddRange(loadResults);

myList.DoSomethingWithValues();
```

EDIT: Changed Select to SelectMany as pointed out by Reed Copsey.

Comment: You get a +1 from me now ;)  The one thing (which may or may not matter) - I like this option, but it does change the order of the elements in "myList" compared to the original. This may or may not matter in this routine, but it's worth noting.

Answer (score -1):

Unless there's compelling reason to try to run them all at once I'd suggest you just run them all in a single asynchronous method.

Compelling reason might be heavy disk/database IO that would mean running more than one background thread would actually allow them to run simultaneously.  If most of the initialization is actually code logic, you might find that multiple threads actually result in slower performance.

Comment: Very few routines called `Load` would be 100% CPU-bound, and very few CPUs are single-core. I'm willing to bet that parallelism would rarely result in slower performance in this case.

Comment: Unless this was nearly pure disk IO bound, running in parallel would likely dramatically improve perf.  Heavy DB IO is helped tremendously by parallel operation, as most DB servers handle concurrency quite well.  Pure CPU bound work would still help tremendously unless it's a single core system, in which case the TPL options above still handle this scenario fairly well...

Comment: As I said in my answer : heavy disk/database use *is a compelling reason*, but naming a method `Load` doesn't always imply it's doing any heavy lifting.  My point was that the OP didn't specify what the methods were doing, and simply assuming that threading or parallelising a bunch of method calls will improve performance is *never* the right approach.

Comment: Caveat: even if the workload is trivially parallelizable, starting Tasks has considerable overhead and isn't worth it for trivial computations - and lots of computations *are* trivial.  Assuming that you're dealing with methods taking milliseconds or more, `Task` can be worth it.